# In Laravel how to dynamically add country code to route

Tags: laravel

In my Laravel project I want to do functionality like when someone hit url for eg. Xyz.com then if it open in India then dynamically append country code to url like Xyz.com/In load view for india information.
How to do this in Laravel-8.

Comment: Please add a relevant code snippet of what you tried. StackOverflow is not a code writing service. Please read [ask] and [help/on-topic]

Comment: There are many similar questions here already, did you try searching?

Answer (score 1):

For this topic, you can read [Routing parameters](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-parameters) from the laravel docs.

```php
Route::get('/country/{country}', function ($country) {
    return $country;
});
```